# Responsive Breadcrumbs with CSS Triangles and margin between items

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sass, breadcrumbs

I want to make a breadcrumb simulating a progress bar , just like this

[image]

By default all items are gray and class " completed" the color green. But I have a problem with the last element , playing with width : spare me a space or skip to the next line .
[image]
This is my code (scss & html):

```css
ul.progress-tracker {
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  &: before, &: after {
    clear: both;
  }
  li {
    list-style: none;
    &: first-child {
      a: before {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    &:last-child {
      padding-right: 8px;
      a {
        margin: 0;
        min-width: 30.09%;
        padding: 3px 0 0 8px;
        &: after {
          display: none;
        }
      }
    }
    a {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      float: left;
      height: 8px;
      background: tint($light-blue, 60%);
      text-align: center;
      padding: 3px 4px 0 8px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 10px 0 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      min-width: 31%;
      &: before {
        content: "";
        border-color: transparent;
        border-top: 4px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid $light-gray;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      &:after {
        content: "";
        border-top: 4px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid tint($light-blue, 60%);
        position: absolute;
        right: -4px;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
      }
    }
    a.completed {
      background-color: $primary-green;
      &: after {
        border-left-color: $primary-green;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="progress-tracker">
  <li>
    <a class="completed">

    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>

    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>

    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does there need to be text inside these "breadcrumbs"?

Comment: for resolutions phone (xs) does not have text inside, it is possible that for versions of table and desk in the number of step (1,2,3) turns

Comment: Alright. And what is the problem? As far as I can see, you just displayed three images and showed your code. You say that you want to display the progress bar "just like this", where a bar that terminates without an end is drawn, but then you say you have a problem alluding to absense of pointy end.

Comment: My problem is that I can not have the bar 100% wider than the screen, which mark in the red box .

Comment: Will you have text in those `a` elements?

Comment: @amn: for resolutions phone (xs) does not have text inside, it is possible that for versions of table and desk in the number of step (1,2,3) turns

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```css
ul.progress-tracker {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.progress-tracker:before, ul.progress-tracker:after {
  clear: both;
}
ul.progress-tracker li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: calc(100% / 3);
  padding-right: 5px;
}
ul.progress-tracker li:first-child a:before {
  display: none;
}
ul.progress-tracker li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0px;
}
ul.progress-tracker li:last-child a {
  margin: 0;
}
ul.progress-tracker li:last-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
ul.progress-tracker li a {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  background: #bcc3c4;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
ul.progress-tracker li a:before {
  content: "";
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid #EAF3E3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
ul.progress-tracker li a:after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid #bcc3c4;
  position: absolute;
  right: -4px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
ul.progress-tracker li a.completed {
  background-color: #8ABD2E;
}
ul.progress-tracker li a.completed:after {
  border-left-color: #8ABD2E;
}
```

```html
        <ul class="progress-tracker">
            <li>
                <a class="completed">
                    
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="completed">

                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>
                    
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```